# suddenly password column throws: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use PHP PDO to do a one-off replace of plain-text passwords in my dev database (see below).

I use numerous other PDO INSERT and UPDATE statements without any trouble - or at least without this issue, so what is going wrong here? It seems that it suddenly translates the column name `password` as a reserved word, and sets the column name to the hashed value! Why is this a problem now, but never when I updated passwords and other member details before? (Have tried with and without backticks.)

```
foreach($pwdArr as $key => $value)
{
        $value = strtolower ($value);
        $value = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $updatePwdSQL = "UPDATE `member` SET `password` = $value WHERE `id` = $key";
    $update = $PDOdbObject->prepare($updatePwdSQL);
        $update->execute();
}
```

Thanks if anyone can clarify!

Comment: `SET \`password`` = $value` should be `SET \`password\` = '$value'`

Comment: Problem aside, I think you're using PDO the "wrong" way: putting variable directly into query, and preparing the (structure-ly) same query over and over again.

Comment: thanks - but as i said before, this is a one-off on my dev db. i don't use PDO this way anywhere else (i.e. in the running application).

Comment: so by the way - is this voted down because no one else is ever likely to have the same problem (i'd be surprised ...) or because no one can bear the thought of an imperfect PDO query for a one-off fix? i'd really like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is weird but I think you should try to change your query to:

```
 $updatePwdSQL = "UPDATE `member` SET `password` = '$value' WHERE `id` = $key";
```

You should add quotes around `$value`

Remark:
The comment that was posted above by Passerby is a good comment and it's advisable that you'll embrace it!

Comment: haha - i'd love to upvote it @alfasin - but my reputation is lousy because people keep voting me down :-D!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is like this, using PDO:bindValue for foreach

```
foreach($pwdArr as $key => $value)
{
        $value = strtolower ($value);
        $value = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $updatePwdSQL = "UPDATE `member` SET `password` = :value WHERE `id` = :key";
        $update = $PDOdbObject->prepare($updatePwdSQL);
        $update->bindValue (':value', $value);
        $update->bindValue (':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $update->execute();
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks - i do this the "correct" way in REAL code, but not for this one-off quick-and-dirty update.